# Google sign in using firebase to check user already exists

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a google sign in button and stored in firebase.
The code is as follows:

```
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {



        if let error = error {
           // ...
           return
         }

         guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
         let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

         Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in

           if error == nil {
            print("google signed in")

           }
           else
           {
               print(error?.localizedDescription)
           }


         }
    }
```

It should not allow the user to sign in via google in the firebase if such a user is not created in firebase database.
How to verify that and then alert the user about this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the user does not exist in firebase database already".  Please edit the question to say more about the situation you're trying to avoid.

Comment: The user is not created in firebase database then it should prompt the user that such user does not exist in firebase.

Comment: Are you asking how to notify a user that they have not created an account yet?

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous as if you want to prevent a user from signing in if they don't have an account, the regular `.signIn` function will do that; if there's no account, they will be prevented from signing in and the function will return `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound` in the error parameter so you can notify the user there's no account.

Comment: Yes exactly i want to notify the user if the account is not created yet.  Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                if error._code == AuthErrorCode.userNotFound.rawValue {
                    //Present_your_desired_alert_here
                }
            }

        } With this method, i dont know if the user is alerted if the account is not created yet in firebase.

Comment: Right. When the error is returned YOU notify the user with whatever messaging you want - if they don't have an account, they cannot sign in. So just say *Mr. User, you don't have an account yet, please click the Sign Up button to create one*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to check if a user exists you can use a method `fetchSignInMethods`.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {



    if let error = error {
       // ...
       return
     }

     guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

     guard let email = user.profile.email else { return }

     Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(email: email) { (providers, error) in
       if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
       }

       if let providers = providers { 
        //This returns an array and will tell you if an user exists or not
        //If the user exists you will get providers.count > 0 else 0

         if providers.count > 0 {
          //User Exists and you can print the providers like [google.com, facebook.com] <-- Providers used to sign in
         } else {
          //Show Alert user does not exist
         }
       }


     }

}
```

Comment: guard let email = user.email else { return } this shows error..it says Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'email'

Comment: @Saranya Updated answer.

Comment: You can use the same way. From Facebook button you will get the user's email follow this same approach. It will be better if you create a separate function for it as it can be used with more providers to check whether the user exists or not.

Comment: @Saranya This is a great answer but seems like an overkill for what was asked and doesn't really answer the question *It should not allow the user to sign*. It seems the objective of the question was to not allow a user to sign if if they don't have an account established. The regular `.signIn` function will return an error of `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound` within the closure if the user was not found when they attempt to sign in so that can be used to notify the user the account doesn't exist and also prevents them from logging in.

Comment: Worked for me, I just checked `providers.count > 0`

Answer (score 0):

So You want only one condition, i.e if user is not found, you will present an Alert to the User that 'User is not created in database' right !

For that you can check the error code of GoogleSignIn, like :

```
guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                if error._code == AuthErrorCode.userNotFound.rawValue {
                    //Present_your_desired_alert_here
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: i will check with this method

Comment: For this method,should the multiple accounts per email address need to be enabled in firebase?

Comment: This will create an auth user with Google credential if not exist, just want to know if it exist